# WIX - run a VB script from working directory after installation.

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I am having a issue with WIX. During installation of MSI I want to verify .NET framework 4.0 is installed or not, if not then I have to install from dotnet msi.

As I can not call a MSI from another MSI so I wrote a VB script that perform .NET framework verification and installation.

Now the problem is, I want to run that VB script after installation from installed directory. I tried all possible ways but not able to get it.

Here is the piece of WIX code.

```
    <CustomAction Id="StartAppOnExit" FileKey="DotNetFrameworkCheck.vbs"
   Execute="deferred" Return="asyncWait" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="StartAppOnExit" After="InstallFinalize"></Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Where FileKey is

```
 <File Id="DotNetFrameworkCheck.vbs" Source="Build_\message.vbs" />
```

May I know the wrong thing in code??

Comment: Beware VBScript custom actions: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robmen/archive/2004/05/20/136530.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way to install .NET or other prerequisites is from a bootstrapper exe. This bootstrapper will first invoke the .NET installer, and then your own MSI.

Wix 3.6 includes features to generate such a bootstrapper. See [How To: Install the .NET Framework Using Burn](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/install_dotnet.htm).

Comment: Oh! that I know, and I did also but here, the requirement is to run the installed script. That script will do some other prerequisites checks also...

Answer (score 0):

Moreover all custom actions must be executed between `InstallInitialize` and `InstallFinalize`. You need to change your `InstallExecuteSequence`.